how would you start a nest.js application without `nest start` command?
I use npm publish to pack my application and run node ./dist/index.js to run it inside docker container in production. As nest.js has kind of special command to start, I wonder if I can integrate it somehow to my setup.
I get the app output under dist when I run nest build which looks pretty node ./dist/main.jsable. But I think it doesn't load configurations like .env when run under dist.
Is there anyone handling nest.js deployment without making nest or npm commands as a dependency?

Never did that, but just a question: why would you want that?

@mikegross as i said, i pack and containerize the application in production. in the container, i just have node and the application's dist which is pure javascript. so i just node dist/main.js inside the container to start the app, no dependencies.

The @nestjs/cli should never be a production dependency in the first place. It's essentially a compiler wrapper and node executor. After you nest build in a build step you can simply node dist/main or node dist/src/main depending on your build and start so long as the production dependencies exist. In fact, if you look in a nest new package.json you'll see a start:prod command that is just node dist/main and that @nestjs/cli is a devDependency

seeing a lot of configuration in the cli's start command had confused me about this but i guess you are right, there should be no trouble while doing node dist/main.js. also strangely there was no guide in nest docs about deploying. anyway, i will try to deploy it shortly.
